# How to modify only part of a function through the filter

Tags: filters, user-registration

I'm trying to edit part a function that validates user registration and I need to change the language of the error response because I modified sanitize_user() to disallow "@" and ".". So I need to edit the error response under..

// User name must pass WP's validity check.

And change that error text response to something of my choosing. How am I hooking in and modifying just part?

```
function bp_core_validate_user_signup( $user_name, $user_email ) {

    // Make sure illegal names include BuddyPress slugs and values
    bp_core_flush_illegal_names();

    // WordPress Multisite has its own validation. Use it, so that we
    // properly mirror restrictions on username, etc.
    if ( function_exists( 'wpmu_validate_user_signup' ) ) {
        $result = wpmu_validate_user_signup( $user_name, $user_email );

    // When not running Multisite, we perform our own validation. What
    // follows reproduces much of the logic of wpmu_validate_user_signup(),
    // minus the multisite-specific restrictions on user_login
    } else {
        $errors = new WP_Error();

        // Apply any user_login filters added by BP or other plugins before validating
        $user_name = apply_filters( 'pre_user_login', $user_name );

        // User name can't be empty
        if ( empty( $user_name ) ) {
            $errors->add( 'user_name', __( 'Please enter a username', 'buddypress' ) );
        }

        // user name can't be on the blacklist
        $illegal_names = get_site_option( 'illegal_names' );
        if ( in_array( $user_name, (array) $illegal_names ) ) {
            $errors->add( 'user_name', __( 'That username is not allowed', 'buddypress' ) );
        }

        // User name must pass WP's validity check
        if ( ! validate_username( $user_name ) ) {
            $errors->add( 'user_name', __( 'Usernames can contain only letters, numbers, ., -, and @', 'buddypress' ) );
        }

        // Minimum of 4 characters
        if ( strlen( $user_name ) < 4 ) {
            $errors->add( 'user_name',  __( 'Username must be at least 4 characters', 'buddypress' ) );
        }

        // No underscores. @todo Why not?
        if ( false !== strpos( ' ' . $user_name, '_' ) ) {
            $errors->add( 'user_name', __( 'Sorry, usernames may not contain the character "_"!', 'buddypress' ) );
        }

        // No usernames that are all numeric. @todo Why?
        $match = array();
        preg_match( '/[0-9]*/', $user_name, $match );
        if ( $match[0] == $user_name ) {
            $errors->add( 'user_name', __( 'Sorry, usernames must have letters too!', 'buddypress' ) );
        }

        // Check into signups
        $signups = BP_Signup::get( array(
            'user_login' => $user_name,
        ) );

        $signup = isset( $signups['signups'] ) && ! empty( $signups['signups'][0] ) ? $signups['signups'][0] : false;

        // Check if the username has been used already.
        if ( username_exists( $user_name ) || ! empty( $signup ) ) {
            $errors->add( 'user_name', __( 'Sorry, that username already exists!', 'buddypress' ) );
        }

        // Validate the email address and process the validation results into
        // error messages
        $validate_email = bp_core_validate_email_address( $user_email );
        bp_core_add_validation_error_messages( $errors, $validate_email );

        // Assemble the return array
        $result = array(
            'user_name'  => $user_name,
            'user_email' => $user_email,
            'errors'     => $errors,
        );

        // Apply WPMU legacy filter
        $result = apply_filters( 'wpmu_validate_user_signup', $result );
    }

    return apply_filters( 'bp_core_validate_user_signup', $result );
}
```

I realize this is a plugin function but my question is about filters so I'm asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter in questions filters an array, populated as follows:

```
$result = array(
        'user_name'  => $user_name,
        'user_email' => $user_email,
        'errors'     => $errors,
);
```

The error message is contained within the `WP_Error` object stored with the key `errors`.

The `WP_Error` object (see [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error)) store no, one or more errors in a private 2-D array indexed by error code. Each error code can have multiple error messages assigned to it.

Unfortunately you can only *add* errors, you cannot remove them, their messages or even change them, (see [trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/28092) - if you're lucky I might submit a patch ;) ).

The only (hacky) solution is to create a new `WP_Error` object from the given one, omitting the error message you want to change.

#### Health warnings

- We are comparing human-readable strings, this could quite possibly change with no announcement. This is a hack after all.
- Similarly the error code may change, without announcement. :/
- Having observed BP's code, even *with* a patch for the track ticket mentioned above, you still can't target just the error message you want without using the human-readable string - all errors use the same code!

With that in mind,

```
function wpse161688_modifity_errors( $result ){

     $original_error = $result['errors'];
     $new_error      = new WP_Error();

     foreach( $original_error->get_error_codes() as $code ){
          foreach(  $original_error->get_error_messages( $code ) as $message ){  
                if( $code != 'user_name' || $message != __( 'Usernames can contain only letters, numbers, ., -, and @', 'buddypress' ) ){
                     $new_error->add( $code, $message );
                }else{
                     //This is the (code,message) pair we want to target...
                     $message = '... change message here ... ';
                     $new_error->add( $code, $message );
                }
          }
     }

     $result['errors'] = $new_error;

     return $result;
}
add_filter( 'wpmu_validate_user_signup', 'wpse161688_modifity_errors' );
```

*Please note that this is completely untested.*

Comment: Pretty freakin great explanation. I really appreciate it..thanks.

Comment: The code as is actually stops sending errors to both the username and email while the errors still get sent to password and profile name.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Corrected now. (You need to modify `$result` and return it).